# Use DbProviderFactory for SQL and Oracle DB to get the schema table

Tags: .net, sql, oracle

I am using .NET with sql/oracle server.

I want to get the schema(datatype,columnname,etc...) of the sql result from:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tablename
```

...or:

```
SELECT customername, companyname 
  FROM tablename
```

I do not want to execute for the real data. I just want to get the metadata behind that result without executing this statement... It worked in C++ but how in Ado.Net with C# ?

Comment: When posting code inline with your question, surround it by backticks (_`_) to make is stand out as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.createcommand.aspx), then look at [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6wk60t6.aspx), and specifically, the [CommandBehaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx) SchemaOnly:

> The query returns column information only.

The documenations also mentions some SQL Server specifics, but handily I was just browsing the OracleClient classes, and they seem to respect this flag also. I don't know if it's guaranteed for other database providers.